# Swing repaint() not working

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

```
 class ballbouncepanel extends JPanel
{
        public void start()
            {

                Timer timer;
                final int FREQ = 45;
                timer = new Timer(FREQ, new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                    {
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect();
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return new Dimension(250,200);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            rect.draw(g);
            rect.move(g);
            rect.erase(g);
        }
}

class Rect
{
    public int xLocation = 0;
    public int yLocation = 0;
    public int xVelocity = 10;
    public int yVelocity = 10;

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.fillRect(xLocation, yLocation, 20, 20);
    }
    public void move(Graphics g)
    {
        xLocation += xVelocity;
        yLocation += yVelocity;
    }
    public void erase(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(xLocation, yLocation, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

The new error is that now my repaint method isn't working.

Above is my code for the frame that I got that I want to paint on, I understand paint using a applet or JApplet, but I am trying to do what I did in a applet on Swing, and now im running into problems, I have looked up many tutorials on how to implement graphics in, but most of them is just running a main graphics, I need mine to be in this specific frame(BB). If anyone could help me understand or point me to a beginners tutorial for it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: See the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: _"I understand paint using a applet or JApplet, but I am trying to do what I did in a applet on Swing"_ It's the same concept. fyi `JApplet` _is_ a swing component. _"and now im running into problems"_ - What problems? Show some code. The code you've posted shows nothing about painting.

Comment: ok I editied it. The new problem is that it is not repainting. Sorry for the no code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just forgetting to call the `start()` method of your `ballbouncepanel`. Also a note: you're `move()` method does no painting, so take out the `Graphics` argument and just call it in the timer

Also not sure what the `erase` method is supposed to do, but I'm thinking you want to change color every tick of the timer. In that case, just keep a `color` variable, and just change that variable. You can see the example below

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class bounceballpanel extends JPanel {
    public void start() {

        Timer timer;
        final int FREQ = 45;
        timer = new Timer(FREQ, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                rect.move();
                rect.changeColor();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    Rect rect = new Rect();

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 200);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        rect.draw(g);
        //rect.erase(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                bounceballpanel panel = new bounceballpanel();
                panel.start();
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Rect {
    public int xLocation = 0;
    public int yLocation = 0;
    public int xVelocity = 10;
    public int yVelocity = 10;

    Color color = Color.cyan;

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(xLocation, yLocation, 20, 20);
    }

    public void move() {
        xLocation += xVelocity;
        yLocation += yVelocity;
    }

    public void changeColor() {
        if (color == Color.cyan) {
            color = Color.white;
        } else {
            color = Color.cyan;
        }
    }

    /*
    public void erase(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(xLocation, yLocation, 20, 20);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, but now im making a button add a int to the xvelocity, but its not working due to me trying to reference from it form a static context, but when I add a new Rect, it does nothing

Comment: If the button is a class member of bounceballpanel, you can't use it in the `main` Anything outside the `main` that is not `static` can't be accessed from the `main`. You _can_ add the button to the panel though.

Comment: I got the button, but what would I put the action listener under, which would call the method addx()?

Comment: Just put whatever changes the velocity of the rect. You don't need to call repaint, as the timer already does that.

Comment: yes, but when I put it to call rect.addX() under the actionlistener, it runs into the static error.  And if I put the actionlistener for the button in the rect class, obviously that will run a error cause then it wont be able to find the button

Comment: Is the button in the `main` method? If so, that's why. Read my second comment. You may want to redesign the program, if you want the button in the frame instead of the panel.

Comment: I got it, I had to rethink my logic. Thanks for being patient and for the help! btw I put the method inside the panel, I was thinking the panel was the Class rect, idk why!